# How to extract number from a string in SnowFlake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a string like this to extract the card number,

```
A user entered through a door and his Card number (123456) other text
```

Since there is only one parenthesis,I am able to extract the card number. The solution for this I am using is

> Select "An user entered through a door and his Card number (123456)."
> as card_number_text, substring(card_number_text, POSITION('(',
> card_number_text)+1, POSITION(')', card_number_text) - POSITION('(',
> card_number_text) - 1)

This gives the card number properly. But the problem I facing is when there are two parentheses in the text,

For example, a text like this won't give a proper card number

```
A user entered through a door (using an anti-pass) and his Card number (123456) other text
```

Comment: What exatly is the rule for finding the credit number? Is it the only numeric value inside parantheses? Or how else do we recognize it? Will you have to deal with phrases like "A young user (16) entered a hut with her credit card (123456) where she met several men (7), who happened to be dwarfs."? You need a rule. Once you have that, you may be able to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` for the task (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, the rule is simple . Card number will come always after the text Card number  enclosed in Paranthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not splitting the data based on string `Card number (`. And then pick up second part as card number after little cleanup.

```
select 
replace(                               -- this removes extra character and returns 123456
split_part(data_col,'Card number (',2) -- this results 123456).
,').') as card_number
```

It doesnt matter if card number is a numeric or alphanumeric.